# Is there way to get MAC Os Lion installer having mac book air 2011?

Tags: macos, macbook-air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean install Mac OS X Lion on new SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/359451/clean-install-mac-os-x-lion-on-new-ssd)

I have it installed in my Macbook Air, and I wanna get portable distributive.

Comment: Actually I think Yura is looking for a "portable distribution" of Lion.  Something like what would come on a thumb drive.  The article you are quoting only works for other Macs that are 2011 or newer (came with Lion preinstalled).  The idea of a portable distro is to have one for use if the system didn't come preinstalled with Lion (I believe).

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what's really being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

I believe this is what you are looking for:
http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/08/make-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-installer-from-a-usb-flash-drive/

You can also use Carbon Copy Cloner to make an exact copy of your internal hard disk, and boot from it externally.