# Can I download the OS X Mountain Lion update and share it with my family?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I have purchased and downloaded the 4 GB Mountain Lion update. Can I burn this to a DVD and share it around with my family? Is it locked to my Apple ID or anything?

Comment: No this is illegal

Comment: @KronoS No, not always, see Daniel's answer below.

Comment: Have you paid the upgrade fee for each computer you wish to install it on?

Comment: @slhck I stand corrected.

Comment: @KronoS yeah I knew apple was ok with you doing this for the snow leopard & lion releases so I figured this one might be the same.

Comment: In Ask Different: [What actions are performed by Install OS X Mountain Lion.app that are not performed by InstallESD.dmg without the app?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/59239/8546)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can burn a DVD from it. The instructions are [the same as for OS X Lion](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/07/18/make-an-os-x-lion-boot-disc/) and need to be performed before you upgrade (otherwise you don't have the *Install OS X Mountain Lion* application anymore).

[If you don't have the download anymore, you can probably get it from somewhere else](https://superuser.com/questions/359451/clean-install-mac-os-x-lion-on-new-ssd/359454#359454); since you bought it this could be legal depending on your jurisdiction. The `InstallESD.dmg` MD5 checksum for Mountain Lion as released yesterday is `8b4869920cd740414fe6b7e3f0b1be3e`.

When installing OS X ML from scratch, it (repeatedly) asks for your Apple ID, but entering yours can be skipped in all of these dialogs.

---

Note that the following restrictions apply ([license agreement PDF](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX108.pdf), emphasis mine):

> B. Mac App Store License. If you obtained a license for the Apple Software from the Mac App Store, then subject to the terms and conditions of this License and as permitted by the Mac App Store Usage Rules set forth in the App Store Terms and Conditions (http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/ww/) (“Usage Rules”), you are granted a limited, non-transferable, non-exclusive license:
>
> (i) to download, install, use and run for personal, non-commercial use, **one (1) copy of the Apple Software directly on each Apple-branded computer running OS X Lion or OS X Snow Leopard (“Mac Computer”) that you own or control**;

This is in contrast to the section A above it, restricting the license of a preinstalled Mountain Lion to the single computer it came bundled with. So in *some situations*, you are allowed to install one ML purchase on multiple computers.

So it *could* be legal to install it to other computers in your home you control (e.g. your children's), but it's prohibited to share it more widely.

Comment: Wow what a detailed an insightful answer. Thankyou

Comment: Voted up, with a side note: in the future, `InstallESD.dmg`  with checksum `8b4869920cd740414fe6b7e3f0b1be3e` may not install Mountain Lion to some Mountain Lion-capable hardware. (As a comparison: [10.7.2 is insufficient for some Lion-capable hardware](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/10/22/removing-and-rebuilding-a-malfunctioning-recover-hd-partition/).) For this reason I encourage users to set aside an updatable copy of Apple's `Install OS X Mountain Lion.app` in its entirety – to not rely on the `.dmg` alone.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin True. Newer hardware usually requires a more up to date version of Mac OS X.